# How do I fix this if shell statement with "[" command?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

Why do I get these errors:

```
-bash: [: missing `]'
grep: ): No such file or directory
grep: ]: No such file or directory
```

when I run this in `sh` or `bash`:

```
if [ \( lsusb -t | grep -q 'qmi_wwan' \) ]; then
    echo 'yes'
else
    echo 'no'
fi
```

Comment: Don't you need to escape the | as well?

Comment: True, forgot about `|`. Now I'm getting this: `-bash: [: ')' expected, found -t`

Comment: `[` is a command (an alternate name for the command also called `test`), not shell syntax, and it only performs a limited number of operations; `lsusb` is not one of them. See its documentation at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: ...also, `|` behaves the same way in the presence of `[` as it behaves in any other context: it ends one simple command and starts a new one, with the stdout of the command on its left connected to the stdin of the command on its right. So you're running `[ '(' usb -t` as one command, and `grep -q 'qmi_wwan' ')' ']'` as a second command. Neither of those is useful.

Comment: Now, you _could_ run `[ "$(lsusb -t | grep qmi_wwan)" ]`, and _that_ would be useful -- inefficient compared to just `lsusb -t | grep -q qmi_wwan`, but useful. (When you pass `[` a single argument other than the expected terminating `]`, as that does, it tests whether that argument is empty; `[ "string" ]` is identical to `[ -n "string" ]`, `test "string"`, or `test -n "string"` -- removing the `-q` was necessary because when it's present, the stdout from `grep` is _always_ empty, so the test result would always be false).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the exit code of the `grep` command, use it *instead of* the `[` command:

```
if lsusb -t | grep -q 'qmi_wwan'
then
  echo "Yes"
fi
```

Comment: I didn't post the full if statement which includes logical operators and other statements. But this subset of statements returns the same error, so I didn't include the rest to minimize the confusion.

Comment: Do you mean "I'm not sure how to apply this solution because I don't know how to use logical operators outside of `[`?" You can use `!`, `||` and `&&` for not/or/and with other commands, including `[`

Comment: I checked the command without `[` before and it works fine, but I wanted to check why it didn't work with `[`.

Comment: Because you aren't running the command anymore; you're running `[` with the *text* of the command as its arguments.